# Best method to display Country, State, Country code, ISD code in my aspx page

Tags: asp.net

Can anybody help me?

I want a method to display Country, State, Country code, ISD code in cascading drop down on my `aspx` page. I am using VS2005 and also I have to get the database for it in XML.

Should I use AJAX + web service?

Comment: The "Best" way depends on a number of factors. What do you want to get out of the display of the data. If it is of primary importance, I'd render it with the page. If it is of secondary importance then an AJAX call once the page is rendered may be fine. If you are able to get all the primary data and this data at the same time then you can reduce server load by rendering it all a the same time.

Comment: Consider using google geo location API. http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider Writing a user control which will include code to display and get countries etc. So when ever you need to display countries you just need to drop the user control in multiple aspx pages. this way you get Performance benefits too.

- Since the countries are not often changed you can easily enable User control level caching etc.

Comment: thank u for ur response , but I need the list accordingly to be displayed on my Page, Sorry for not mentioning it before....!!